# Was a scene cut from "There Will Be Blood", where the adopted son explains oil business?

Tags: alternate-version, there-will-be-blood

I distinctly remember a charming scene in which H. W., dressed in his suit, explains the business of drilling very articulately to a little girl (perhaps the girl who grows up to be his wife). This was I thought besides charming also clever and even plausible -- a little kid who literally grew up among oil wells.

I am now watching again this movie on Showtime -- I have seen it many times now -- and I believe this scene has been cut. Am I right, does anyone else remember this scene?

If I am right about it being cut, that is a puzzling decision. I further think that more about the kid learning the business and maybe less about religion would have been an improvement.

Note: just saw a scene where H. W. talks to girl (it is whom he marries) and she asks about money but I remember more and he was wearing a suit.

Comment: I think I remember it too, yes.

Comment: @Joachim: The scene I saw last night was him talking to the girl about money in like a barn and that her father beats her for not praying comes up. No precocious drilling discussion beyond brief chat about how much her family might make.